# How to display Live Stream video with RTMP in viewer from URL stream in Flutter

Tags: flutter, rtmp, viewer

I use apivideo_live_stream to implement live steam with RTMP in Flutter. I want to display video steam play back in viewer. How can do it? Please help me. Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBwVQ.png)